# Storage site for creations

Tags: modeling

Where are the images/characters/models that someone creates stored?  Privately by the individual and/OR somewhere in Blender?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by "somewhere in blender".. Are you asking if blender forces some kind of cloud storage? In that case the answer is no.

Comment: B"H Thank you That was the question.

Comment: Adel what does B"H mean?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, like most home computer programs, Blender stores what you create in the directory of your choice. When you press File->Save (as) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the *.blend* file you'll get a File Save dialogue where you can pick where to save it and how to name it.

`.blends` are not stored inside the Blender App.

Comment: B"H Thank you This is how I saved it.  Windows 10 asked "what app" to open the saved file with.

Comment: @Adel I think http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41488/47 will help you with the windows thing, unfortunately I don't have windows.