# How to view the Console

Tags: modeling

December 23, 2018

Blender 2.79

Installed the Add on Trainz Exporter and it is on my Blender Window:

I need to Install the TrainzMeshImporter however; to get it to work.

The console will tell you where it goes. I get the message:

Export failed please check CONSOLE Window

I can't find the Console Window no matter what I do.

There is a button in the upper left hand corner that has a Blue Circle I
This has a selection Python Console but this is not it.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the system console. That's in windows > Toggle system console:
[image]

Do not click the X on the console window since this will close blender. You can close the console only by clicking the toggle system console button again.

**Edit:** Here's how to do it on a mac: [How to open system console to get output from Blender on Mac OS 10?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102860/how-to-open-system-console-to-get-output-from-blender-on-mac-os-10)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I believe that option is only available via windows OS. As a general rule start blender from a terminal.

Comment: I've added the method to do that in mac