# I made something on blender and pressed something and now I don’t know how to get back to what I was doing please help!

Tags: objects

[image]
 I was working on a 3d character and I accidentally pressed something and idk what it was but now all it shows is this and idk how to get out of it and I worked on this for a long time and I would hate to have to delete it

Comment: you have closed your 3D view, you have opened a large Timeline view instead, on the bottom left, click on the clock icon, choose 3D View instead

Comment: `CTRL + SpaceBar` in 2.80, `CTRL + UP` or `CTRL + DOWN` in 2.79

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there are situations were it is hard to fix a UI state by hand.
In those extreme cases my favourite way is:

- Save current blend-file
- Open second blender instance (on OSX via Terminal https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102862/68710)
- click: File>Open
- Open your first blend-file but uncheck "Load UI" (on the left panel) before doing so

[image]

now you got your first file but with startup-file-ui

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you full-screened the timeline
you can just try dragging the left "striped" corner of the screen
down and create a new window

then you can select "3d viewport"

or you could just click on the clock in the lower-left corner and change that to 
"3d viewport"

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have removed the 3D view. Don't worry, you can get it back. What you are looking at is the timeline usually at the bottom of the screen stretched to fill it. Click and drag the little thumb grip in the upper right-hand corner of the area where the timeline is. Drag it downward: A new timeline editor will appear in the space. Drag it all the way down to where the original timeline is only about half an inch tall. Now, in the header of the new timeline, click the icon in the far left that has the picture of a clock on it: this opens a menu to select the editor type. Change it from "timeline" to "3D view".

Here are the manual sections related to the topic.

[Areas (invilving splitting and joining)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html)
[Editors (What the "timeline" and "3D view" are)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/index.html)