# Add-on list not showing up

Tags: add-on

I really have no idea what is going on with this. I’ve been using Blender since 2013 so I am pretty well used to the interface. Please give helpful answers if you have any. Basically I opened the Preferences window and went to the Add-on tab and I got this. As you can see there is no list of standard add-ons[image]

Comment: Can you check if there are any error written to the console/terminal? Does it help when you start Blender from the command line using the `--factory-startup` flag?

Comment: There are no errors anywhere. I’ve never done the command line thing. I’ll give it a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this on a MAC.

Comment: Open a terminal and write the full path to blender in case you don't have an alias set (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102860/how-to-open-system-console-to-get-output-from-blender-on-mac-os-10) then behind the path put the flag from my last comment and press enter.