# How to view datablock dependency hierarchy?

Tags: python, linked-data, outliner, data-blocks

In my startup file I have various node groups that I keep on hand for common tasks. Sometimes I will add a new node group or material that contains an *existing* group inside it. So what happens is `SwitchNode` becomes `SwitchNode.001`, which not only clutters my .blend, but also makes updating difficult. If I later decide to add a new input socket to `SwitchNode` I have two of them to deal with.

What I am looking for is a way to find where `SwitchNode.001` is being used as a dependency (in what other group or material) - so that I can select `SwitchNode` from the group's drop-down selector instead. Effectively consolidating the .blend so there is only one true `SwitchNode`... and first I want to examine how `SwitchNode.001` is being used, in order to make sure I don't break any functionality when I update my node groups.

One might guess the Outliner would provide such functionality to quickly inspect the dependency hierarchy of whatever datablock you search for. But when I navigate to **Blender File > Node Groups > SwitchNode.001** and R-click then **View > Show Hierarchy**, the Outliner does not show me that datablock's hierarchy, but instead collapses the entire hierarchy so that I need to scroll back up to the top of the Outliner and start over.

**How can I view which materials or node groups are relying on a given node group?**

<sub>Edit: I'm adding the Python tag just in case the only way to do this is with Python. We can remove it later if Python turns out not to be necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The script below lists all node groups and their users as a tree inside the console. Each user displays the node group’s occurrences and its name(s) inside the user (so you can do a ctrl+f for the group). The node groups are also sorted by the number of links/connections so you can find possibly redundant/duplicated node groups.

You will need to have the system console open for Blender, as the output is displayed here. Run the script from within Blender's Text Editor.

```py
from os import system
import os.path
import pkg_resources
import platform
import sys

import bpy
from rich.padding import Padding
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich import print
from rich.rule import Rule
from rich.tree import Tree


def get_values(items_tuple):
    for items in items_tuple:
        try:
            for itm in items:
                if isinstance(itm, int):
                    return itm
        except TypeError:
            pass


installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing = {'rich'} - installed

if missing:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'rich', '--user'])

home_folder = os.path.expanduser("~")
user_site_packages_folder = "{}/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages".format(
  home_folder)
if user_site_packages_folder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(user_site_packages_folder)

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    system("cls")
elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
    system("printf '\\33c\\e[3J'")
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    system("clear")

ng_users_dict = bpy.data.user_map(subset=bpy.data.node_groups)

node_group_users = {
  key: list(value)
  for key, value in bpy.data.user_map(subset=bpy.data.node_groups).items()
  if not isinstance(key, bpy.types.GeometryNodeTree)
}

[
  node_group_users[key].append(len(key.links))
  for key, _value in node_group_users.items()
]
sorted_node_group_users = {
  key: value
  for key, value in sorted(node_group_users.items(), key=get_values)
}

for node_group, users in sorted_node_group_users.items():
    print(Rule(style="grey50"))
    print(
      Panel(node_group.name + "\n[grey50]%s links" % len(node_group.links),
            border_style="dim green",
            width=20))
    panels = []
    count = 0
    for count, usr in enumerate(users):
        if isinstance(usr, bpy.types.Material):
            group_names = [
              node.name for node in usr.node_tree.nodes
              if node.type == 'GROUP' and node.node_tree == node_group
            ]
            panels.append(
              Panel(
                usr.name
                + "[dim grey50]\n(%s)[/][grey50]\n" % usr.user_of_id(node_group)
                + '\n'.join(group_names),
                border_style="dim red",
                width=max(len(group_names[0]) + 4, 20)))
        elif isinstance(usr, bpy.types.NodeTree):
            group_names = [
              node.name for node in usr.nodes
              if node.type == 'GROUP' and node.node_tree == node_group
            ]
            panels.append(
              Panel(
                usr.name
                + "[dim grey50]\n(%s)[/][grey50]\n" % usr.user_of_id(node_group)
                + '\n'.join(group_names),
                border_style="dim green",
                width=max(len(group_names[0]) + 4, 20)))

    tree = Tree("[grey50]%s users:" % count, guide_style="dim grey50")
    [tree.add(pnl) for pnl in panels]
    print(Padding.indent(tree, 2))

print(Rule(style="grey50"))
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer, it looks like it's an interesting tool. Would you mind adding a screenshot of the expected output for reference ? :)

Comment: From what I see in the screenshot, this looks very useful! I haven't managed to get it set up right though. I [launched Blender from the console (in macOS)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102860/). Then, I pasted the line to import pip from within Blender's Python console. I got `SyntaxError: incomplete input` and the caret `^` points to the beginning of `'--user’` (Note that I have tried changing "user" to my actual system user name - neither way works.) What am I doing wrong? Can I use Homebrew to install it instead of pip? (I'll wait for advice before I go breaking stuff...)

Comment: @Mentalist Oops, a curly quote was in `'--user’` Fixed my original comment now

Comment: Thanks for taking another look and revising. Unfortunately I've run into another issue. I get: `NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined.` Since 'Rule' was supposed to be defined by `from rich.rule import Rule`, I guess this means **rich** still hasn't been installed successfully. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @Mentalist The site packages directory most likely isn't added to `PATH` – I've updated the code now with a fix

Comment: Thank you! It's working now! This is really helpful. I can finally clean up my duplicate data.